# Assigning a list to data frame - getting an error: invalid factor level, NA generated

Tags: r, list, dataframe, error-handling

I am creating a list of numbers and characters inside a loop and assigning that list to a data frame. I have defined each variable before hand and I am not using factor (at least I feel that way). Basically, I want to create a data frame with the variables I have mentioned. Here's the code I am trying to work with:

```
NumToShow    = numeric(0)
MatToShow    = character()
flag         = numeric(0)

datalist = data.frame(NumToShow,MatToShow,flag)

for (i in 1:3){
  NumToShow = i
  MatToShow = "aaa"
  flag = i^2

  Row_i = list(NumToShow,MatToShow,flag)
  # Combining all the data
  datalist[i,] = Row_i
}
```

I am receiving the error:

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "aaa") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I am not exactly sure why I am getting it. Any help will be appreciated. I apologize if this is something silly. Thank you :)

Comment: This is more of a warning then an error. In `datalist`,  `MatToShow` is a _factor_. During the loop you assign values to it, which are not element of `levels(MatToShow)`. Those values become `NA`. Solution: Add the value(s) to `levels(MatToShow)` or use _character_ vectors instead of _factors_, e.g. by specifiying `data.frame(NumToShow,MatToShow,flag, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: This is a very bad pattern for adding data into a data.frame row-by-row. in this simple example you can do `data.frame(NumToShow=1:3, MatToShow="aaa", flag=(1:3)^2)`. But it would be better to describe what you are really trying to do. Chances are there are better ways in R

Comment: `?data.frame`, then look on the argument `stringsAsFactors`. I often do the same mistake myself.

Comment: MrFlick, I will create another post and explain exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `?data.frame()`:

```
data.frame(..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
           check.names = TRUE, fix.empty.names = TRUE,
           stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

And then type:

```
default.stringsAsFactors()
# [1] TRUE
```

You need to explicitly set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in order for `data.frame()` to not treat characters as factor.

Comment: Thank you! This works :) In future, I will be more careful to check the defaults in a function.